# AES256 decryption from URL

Tags: java, android, aes, decrypt

Я пытаюсь расшифровать файл *.ovpn который зашифрованный с помощью команды `openssl enc -in infile.txt -out encrypted.dat -e -aes256 -k key_firebase`

Файл скачиваеться по ссылке, но я скачиваю его с помощью следующего кода.

```
       private String enctyptionKey = "63efc5743d9927c5993a05bdc5220b9eca8e38b5df829ca587a57f8ae423676b5fd79f641e375d0a0b3e2e03e7a079ea97cdah26bb2e15213daabb468760f425";

  void main(){
      URL url = new URL("https://encryptedfile.url");
        InputStream inputStream = url.openStream())
         byte[] b = new byte[1024];
                ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                int c;
                while ((c = inputStream.read(b)) != -1) {
                    os.write(b, 0, c);
                }
           String result = De.decryptMsg(os.toByteArray());
    }

    class De {
        public static byte[] hex2byte(byte[] b) {

            if ((b.length % 2) != 0)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("hello");
            byte[] b2 = new byte[b.length / 2];
            for (int n = 0; n < b.length; n += 2) {
                String item = new String(b, n, 2);
                b2[n / 2] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(item, 16);
            }
            return b2;
        }

        public static byte[] decryptMsg(String secretKeyString, byte[] encryptedMsg)
                throws Exception {

    //        String algorithm = "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding";
            String algorithm = "AES";
            // generate AES secret key from the user input secret key
            Key key = new SecretKeySpec(secretKeyString.getBytes(), algorithm);
            // get the cipher algorithm for AES
            Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
            // specify the decryption mode
            c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
            // decrypt the message
            return c.doFinal(encryptedMsg);
        }

    }
```

И я получаю ошибку.
InvalidKeyException: Invalid AES key length: 128 bytes

Но данные нормально расшифровываеться командой

```
openssl enc -in encrypted.rtf -out decrypted.rtf -d -aes256 -k 63efc5743d9927c5993a05bdc5220b9eca8e38b5df829ca587a57f8ae423676b5fd79f641e375d0a0b3e2e03e7a079ea97cdah26bb2e15213daabb468760f425
```

Если кто может указать направление куда смотреть, буду благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

Когда вы выполняете команду `openssl enc -in infile.txt -out encrypted.dat -e -aes256 -k key_firebase`, `key_firebase` - это не ключ, это текст, из которого `openssl` генерирует ключ:

> The password is used to derive the actual key which is used to encrypt
>   your data.

Что бы посмотреть какой ключ был сгенерирован, вы можете добавить параметр `-P` (вывести ключи, но не шифровать) или `-p` (вывести ключи и зашифровать):

```
openssl enc -in infile.txt -out encrypted.dat -e -aes256 -k key_firebase -P
```

8 байт соли, которые использовались для генерации ключа, потом добавляются в начало зашифрованного файла.

Java выдает правильное исключение, для AES256 нужен ключ длиной 32 байта.

Comment: Я думал, что эта строчка генерирует ключ.Key key = new SecretKeySpec(secretKeyString.getBytes(), algorithm);

Comment: Она не генерирует ключ, она просто использует байты, которые вы подаете на вход, как ключ.

Comment: А что нужно сделать что бы получить этот ключ с этой строки? У меня кроме пароля и зашифрованного файла ничего нету.

Comment: Я точно не знаю, нужно читать openssl доки. Я даже читал, алгоритм генерации ключей менялся между версиями.